# Nodejs sendFile() disable line wrap

Tags: node.js, word-wrap, sendfile

I want to open a text file on new tab.
However, this file has long lines which I don't want to wrap.
How do I disable line wrap?

```
let path = '/a.txt';
res.sendFile(path);
```

Comment: does new line includes in content of `a.txt`

Comment: The text file does not wrap long lines if opened with a text editor.